# How to get the result from a loop in (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

i make a programe in wich if there is any capital letter it change all word to capital  otherwise if there is no capital word it print it again without change so i write this code

```
def capital(n):
for word in n:
    if word==word.upper():
        print n.upper()
    else:
        print n
n=raw_input()
print capital(n)
```

the output is like that when i use print instead of return

```
capsLock # if i use return it pritn the first result only 
capsLock
capsLock
capsLock
capsLock
CAPSLOCK  # i want this result when it change all letter to capital words
capsLock
capsLock
capsLock
None
```

if i use return it give me only the first result what i should do

Comment: Construct a new list `[s.upper() for s in n]`, and print it. Or using `map`: `map(lambda x:x.upper(), n)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun if you're going to `map`, just use `map(str.upper, n)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe everyday I learn new things :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
def capital(n):
    for word in n:
        if word==word.upper():
            return n.upper()
    return n

n=raw_input()
print capital(n)
```

The loop stops as soon as a capital is found, otherwise, the original word is returned.